# Why does sockJS add a '/info' to a given websocket url path

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs, java-websocket

I want to open a websocket port with a "webapp/socket.do" path. When I use SockJS and try to initiate the call by code

```
    var socket = new SockJS('/webapp/socket.do');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({}, ...
```

SockJS will by default add a "/info" to the end of the given path. I want to know why? Can this be changed or prevented?

When using this with Spring MVC and have url pattern mappings to DispatcherServlet like `< url-pattern >*.do</url-pattern>`, this will return a 404 error. it is blocked because of the "/info" string added by sockJS to the given url.

Spring web.xml servlet mapping code:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Does any know what sockJS is trying there and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part of the SockJS protocol, and mandatory.
This endpoint is implemented by the server and communicates the server capabilities, such as the supported protocols. See the [relevant part of the SockJS protocol](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-protocol/blob/master/sockjs-protocol.py#L250-L263).

In that case, I guess you need to adapt your servlet mapping not only for this endpoint, but also for other requests that might come in: HTTP UPGRADE requests for websocket, all other requests for [HTTP-based transports supported by SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-browser-html-served-from-http-or-https).